# Django DRF: Make serializer field value equal to another one

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an endpoint to reset the password and have created the serializer, views and I am using django.contrib.auth.forms to get the data and send email to the user.
The form requires to type the new password two times but what I want is, to write it only once and make the value of `new_password2` equal to `new_password1`. For example, I want to change the password on Swagger and it doesn't make sense to type it twice because it is a normal CharField and not a PasswordField.

This is the `serializers.py` ResetPasswordConfirm class

```
class ResetPasswordConfirmSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    new_password1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
    new_password2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
    uid = serializers.CharField()
    token = serializers.CharField()
    set_password_form_class = SetPasswordForm

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ResetPasswordConfirmSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.set_password_form = None

def validate(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        uid = force_text(uid_decoder(value['uid']))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        raise ValidationError({
            'uid': ['Invalid value']
        })

    self.set_password_form = self.set_password_form_class(user=user, data=value)
    if not self.set_password_form.is_valid():
        raise serializers.ValidationError(self.set_password_form.errors)
    if not default_token_generator.check_token(user, value['token']):
        raise ValidationError({
            'token': ['Invalid value']
        })
    return value

def save(self, **kwargs):
    return self.set_password_form.save()
```

And, the API View

```
class ResetPasswordConfirmAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = ResetPasswordConfirmSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

@method_decorator(csrf_protect)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(ResetPasswordConfirmAPIView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response({
        'detail': _("Password has been reset"),
    }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I tried different ways to make `new_password2` == `new_password1` but I get errors. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave only `new_password1` in serializer and update data which you send to form inside `validate` method:

```
class ResetPasswordConfirmSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    new_password1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
    uid = serializers.CharField()
    token = serializers.CharField()
    set_password_form_class = SetPasswordForm

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResetPasswordConfirmSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_password_form = None

    def validate(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            uid = force_text(uid_decoder(value['uid']))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            raise ValidationError({
                'uid': ['Invalid value']
            })

        new_value = value.copy()
        new_value['new_password2'] = value['new_password1'] 

        self.set_password_form = self.set_password_form_class(user=user, data=new_value)
        if not self.set_password_form.is_valid():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(self.set_password_form.errors)
        if not default_token_generator.check_token(user, value['token']):
            raise ValidationError({
                'token': ['Invalid value']
            })
        return value

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        return self.set_password_form.save()
```

But I think it's also possible and more clear to do it without form, you can use django's [`validate_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.password_validation.validate_password) function to validate password. I didn't test it, but you can try something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password

class ResetPasswordConfirmSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    new_password1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
    uid = serializers.CharField()
    token = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            uid = force_text(uid_decoder(value['uid']))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            raise ValidationError({
                'uid': ['Invalid value']
            })

        if not default_token_generator.check_token(user, value['token']):
            raise ValidationError({
                'token': ['Invalid value']
            })
        validate_password(password=value['new_password1'], user=user) 
        return value

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=self.validated_data['uid'])  
        user.set_password(self.validated_data['new_password1'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Didn't think about copying the values and using the new dict to pass to the form.

Comment: @XhensB you are welcome! I've updated my answer with method without form. You can check it also.

Comment: Very helpful answer! :)

Comment: @XhensB after some new edits I hope it's more clear:)

Comment: Definitely :) Now I'm thinking to handle everything in the serializer